# Survey 123 Connect - constraints

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I'd like to apply a constraint to a question in my survey.
The constraint will insure that the number users enter in question B will be smaller or equal to the value users enter in question A.

Example: User enter the number 12 in question A, and then the user try to enter number 13 in question B. That should result in a message saying "Value in question B cannot be larger than the value in question A"

I added the following formula in my XMLForm file under the 'constraint' column for question B:

**.<=${question_A}**

But that does not work (the form allows me to enter a larger number in question B).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

***Correction***

Once published, the constraint was checked once a value was entered.
[image: Published]

***Original Answer:***
Constraints are checked on submission.

Your rule looks correct.
[image: XLSform]

Data can be entered:

[image: Enter Data]

But only went submit is clicked is the constraint checked.
[image: Submitting]

This looks to be a common issue for people since 3.5.
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/constraint-validation-occurs-only-when-the-survey/td-p/798610

Comment: thanks @evv_gis. On my Iphone survey123 app (which is up-to-date) the validation appears once I submit the form (similar to your "corrected" answer). On my survey123 app for desktop the validation kicks in once I enter values that trigger the validation rules (similar to your original answer). Is that simply because of different versions of Survey123?

Comment: @doronwen - I believe so.  For years, Survey123 has had different capabilities/experiences based on the version of the app, the platform running it, etc.