# Constrain values in Survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123-connect

I want to create a constraint so Field A cannot be greater than Field B. Is that done in the constraint column? And what is the correct syntax?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457123/survey-123-connect-constraints